# "Subtype" is incompatible with union type

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I stole some JSON types from [the Flow docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#mixed).

I input an array of strings - annotated `Array<string>` - to a function that outputs a promise with some JSON - annotated `Promise<JSON>`. However, the `JSON` type seems to be incompatible with `Array<string>`.

As I understand it, the above should be compatible, since `JSON` could be `JSONArray` which is `Array<JSON>`, where `JSON` could be `string`.

I made a simpler example than the one in my code, and the last line throws the same error. You can see it in action [here](https://tryflow.org/?code=Ly8gQGZsb3cKCnR5cGUgSlNPTiA9IHN0cmluZyB8IG51bWJlciB8IGJvb2xlYW4gfCBudWxsIHwgSlNPTk9iamVjdCB8IEpTT05BcnJheQp0eXBlIEpTT05PYmplY3QgPSB7IFtrZXk6IHN0cmluZ106IEpTT04gfQp0eXBlIEpTT05BcnJheSA9IEFycmF5PEpTT04+Cgpjb25zdCBzdHJpbmdBcnJheVdpdGhBcnJheUFubm90YXRpb24gOiBBcnJheTxzdHJpbmc+ID0gWyJmb28iXQpjb25zdCBzdHJpbmdBcnJheVdpdGhKU09OQW5ub3RhdGlvbiAgOiBKU09OID0gc3RyaW5nQXJyYXlXaXRoQXJyYXlBbm5vdGF0aW9u)

```
// @flow

type JSON = string | number | boolean | null | JSONObject | JSONArray
type JSONObject = { [key: string]: JSON }
type JSONArray = Array<JSON>

const stringArrayWithArrayAnnotation : Array<string> = ["foo"]

// Line below throws:
// array type
// This type is incompatible with
// union: string | number | boolean | null | JSONObject | JSONArray`
const stringArrayWithJSONAnnotation  : JSON = stringArrayWithArrayAnnotation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array` type is invariant [docs: Array elements](https://flowtype.org/docs/arrays.html#array-elements)

```
type A = Array<number | string>;
declare var x: Array<string>;
const y: A = x // => error: number. This type is incompatible with string
```

so while `string` is a subtype of `number | string`, `Array<string>` is *not* a subtype of `Array<number | string>`